# How to build mysql query with php on the fly

Tags: php, mysqli

My head is smoking ;-) and with all the info i read here, i did not get the resolution.

I have a form like this:
[the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Gh9.jpg)

i need to build a Mysql Query select on the fly. The checkboxes can be different selected. Only one or two or three or four or..., its up to the User. From the selected checkboxes i need to build the Mysql query.
i really will appreciate it, some one can help me.

This is my function. so far... i need to add the AND for the sql query.
i did try a lot but nothing works.

```
    function wdw_get_data_answer_select($mysqli, $array_selected) {
$sql_1 = '';
foreach ($array_selected as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'gender' && !empty($value)) { $sql_1 .= "gender = '".$value."'"; }
    if ($key == 'age' && !empty($value)) { $sql_1 .= "age = '".$value."'"; }
    if ($key == 'education' && !empty($value)) { $sql_1 .= "education = '".$value."'"; }
    if ($key == 'department' && !empty($value)) { $sql_1 .= "department = '".$value."'"; }
}
$sql = "SELECT `gender`,`age`,`education`,`department`,`code_numbers` FROM ".TABLE_ANSWERS_BASIC_SELECT." WHERE ".$sql_1;
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
//printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0 ) {
        $stmt->bind_result($gender, $age, $education, $department, $code_numbers);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $select_content .= $code_numbers.',';
        }
    }
}
$stmt->close();
$select_content = substr($select_content, 0, -1);
return $select_content; }
```

[thats the sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdFc5.jpg)

Example:
if checkbox selected like
TEXT_FEMALE and TEXT_AGE_2 and TEXT_AGE_3 TEXT_EDUCATION_2

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `gender` = TEXT_FEMALE and `age` = TEXT_AGE_2 or `age` = TEXT_AGE_3 and `education` = TEXT_EDUCATION_2;
```

and let say TEXT_AGE_3 don't have a TEXT_FEMALE how i can filter out the TEXT_MALE?
i did try

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `gender` IN('TEXT_FEMALE') and `gender` = TEXT_FEMALE and `age` = TEXT_AGE_2 or `age` = TEXT_AGE_3 and `education` = TEXT_EDUCATION_2;
```

works but
but if checkbox selected like
TEXT_FEMALE and TEXT_AGE_2 and TEXT_AGE_3 TEXT_EDUCATION_2 AND TEXT_DEPARTMENT_1 AND TEXT_DEPARTMENT_2
i did try

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `gender` IN('TEXT_FEMALE') and `gender` = TEXT_FEMALE and `age` = TEXT_AGE_2 or `age` = TEXT_AGE_3 and `education` = TEXT_EDUCATION_2 and `department` = TEXT_DEPARTMENT_1 or `department` = TEXT_DEPARTMENT_2
```

the selected answer is not corect.

- TEXT_FEMALE Ženska
- TEXT_MALE Moški
- TEXT_AGE_1 Pod 30 let
- TEXT_AGE_2 Nad 30 do 50 let
- TEXT_AGE_3 Nad 50 let
- TEXT_EDUCATION_1 Poklicno usposabljanje
- TEXT_EDUCATION_2 Študija
- TEXT_EDUCATION_3 Niti
- TEXT_DEPARTMENT_1 Proizvodnja
- TEXT_DEPARTMENT_2 Uprava
- TEXT_DEPARTMENT_3 Drugo (Vzdrževanje, Logistika, Kakovost)

I hope I have explained it understandably. 
I am a german guy. I hope my english is okay ;-)

Comment: it would be easiest to use an sql builder something like https://github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder this way you can loop through and add selects without having to worry about spaces and other things

Comment: I think you may also have an issue with your encoding on that table

Comment: the issue with my encoding i don't understand too. the datebase is Utf8 the meta tag on the website is utf8. the languages file is utf8 without BOM. i did read a lot about this issue her in stackoverflow too and i try a lot, but nothing works. I am quite familar with PHP and mysql more than 25 years and the encoding issue is only at this database. I dont't know why, its a server in Slowenia. I hope i will find a resolution for that sonn.

Comment: sorry, your answer have nothing do to with my problem. all the query builder follow the sql rules, have to of course.
The problem is the creation on the fly and the correct select. if i use an sql query builder there not fix the problem. i will look further to find a resolution. Devlopment is time intensiv!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

with this library github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder you would do something like this

```
$builder = new MySqlBuilder(); 
$query = $builder->select()
    ->setTable('user')
    ->where();

foreach ($array_selected as $key => $value) {
    $query->in($key,array($value));
}

echo $builder->writeformatted($query); // this will output the sql you need to run
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. i will check it out today and i will inform about.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to use Composer nor any autoload because of the hosting company's restrictions and i don't use any local VM ware or WAMP. the explaning how to install without composer is missing. No explaining what class have to include. So i will check out to find another one, but in my opinion a tool like that will not help so much, because i have to prepare the selected checkbox value for that too. anyway if i get a resolution for my "problem" i will post this here. if someone have another idea,  i really will appreciate more info and help. thank you

Comment: github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder haveis no documention. I did find a lot answer about this class file. I will not use it. anyway, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working. I did change the form. Instead of Checkboxes i use Radio buttons.
I create my own Query on the fly. Thanks to all for help!